# MYSQL get AVG for each row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I need get AVG for each row of table. Lets say we have

```
id  val 
1   5
2   6
3   7
```

I need to get

```
id  val 
1   0.277   (5/18)
2   0.333   (6/18)
3   0.388   (7/18)
```

Can I easy get this in MYSQL without joining with the same table?

Comment: what you are trying to get isn't *average*. where is 28 coming from?

Comment: sorry - its typo. it should be 18. I edited question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sum up the val column and divide the val column by that sum.

```
select id, 1.0*val/(select sum(val) from tablename) val
from tablename
```

Comment: is this is the only way? I noted that I need to do it "without joining with the same table". It is because the initial query for my data to complex and I do not want to execute it twice(

Comment: @VladimirGordienko It's not a join, even naive approach would be to do two separate scans - one to calculate the sum, store and use by query engine as const for the main query. The subquery won't be executed each time for each row in main query. That's perfectly fine solution.

Comment: Really, I made a test with subqueries and looks like MYSQL not executes the same query twice. this solution is fine for me. TY guys!